# Can you build a solid wall of red mushroom in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When growing large red mushrooms in Minecraft using bonemeal, they seem to have a minimum distance, and will grow no closer than one square gap. Without cheating or using creative mode or mods, is there a way to make a solid horizontal wall of red mushroom?

Comment: Untested: It might be possible to plant/bonemeal a shroom, chop down all but the bottom 2-3 stalk blocks, then plant/bonemeal a new shroom beside it. I'll try to test this once I'm home, if no-onehas refuted it by then.

Comment: @Arkive — Sadly, mushrooms refuse to grow without sufficient "air space" above and to the side of them.  Red mushrooms, it seems, require enough space not only for the cap, but for an extra block of air all around.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a piston and a redstone torch (or other redstone circuitry) to move mushrooms blocks around. It will take a while, but it could work.